# сокети в c# подключения к серверу

Tags: c#, сокеты

добрый день у меня проблема с подключением сокетов если вместо url моего сайта написать localhost то все работает но мне нужно подключиться к моему сайту как мне это сделать?
c# client

```
// SocketClient.cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace SocketClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                SendMessageFromSocket(11000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        static void SendMessageFromSocket(int port)
        {
            // Буфер для входящих данных
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            // Соединяемся с удаленным устройством

            // Устанавливаем удаленную точку для сокета
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("http://site.ru/");
            IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, port);

            Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Соединяем сокет с удаленной точкой
            sender.Connect(ipEndPoint);

            Console.Write("Введите сообщение: ");
            string message = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Сокет соединяется с {0} ", sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

            // Отправляем данные через сокет
            int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

            // Получаем ответ от сервера
            int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);

            Console.WriteLine("\nОтвет от сервера: {0}\n\n", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));

            // Используем рекурсию для неоднократного вызова SendMessageFromSocket()
            if (message.IndexOf("<TheEnd>") == -1)
                SendMessageFromSocket(port);

            // Освобождаем сокет
            sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            sender.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Server

```
// SocketServer.cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace SocketServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Устанавливаем для сокета локальную конечную точку
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("http://site.ru/");
            IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 11000);

            // Создаем сокет Tcp/Ip
            Socket sListener = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Назначаем сокет локальной конечной точке и слушаем входящие сокеты
            try
            {
                sListener.Bind(ipEndPoint);
                sListener.Listen(10);

                // Начинаем слушать соединения
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ожидаем соединение через порт {0}", ipEndPoint);

                    // Программа приостанавливается, ожидая входящее соединение
                    Socket handler = sListener.Accept();
                    string data = null;

                    // Мы дождались клиента, пытающегося с нами соединиться

                    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);

                    data += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);

                    // Показываем данные на консоли
                    Console.Write("Полученный текст: " + data + "\n\n");

                    // Отправляем ответ клиенту\
                    string reply = "Спасибо за запрос в " + data.Length.ToString()
                            + " символов";
                    byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reply);
                    handler.Send(msg);

                    if (data.IndexOf("<TheEnd>") > -1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Сервер завершил соединение с клиентом.");
                        break;
                    }

                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    handler.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: я не понял, что ваш код делает и причем тут сайт?

Comment: А ваша серверная часть кода крутится на удаленном сервере, к которому есть доступ по доменному имени или вы хотите чтобы сервер был локальным, но при этом подключаться к нему клиентом не через "localhost" а через например "http://site.ru/" ?

Comment: тут как вот я уже плюс минус понял к локалке он подключается  но у хостингу нет

Comment: пробувал откритий порт 443 и 80